# Chrome Extension User Interface

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, user-interface, google-chrome-extension

I have written my Google  Chrome extension and now have a basic interface for Options and Browser Action Popups. But the look and feel differs in Mac, Windows and Linux.

I want to create the same look and feel for cross platform, and a bit fancier if possible. I mean I want all possible HTML elements, e.g. checkbox, radio, select, option tag to style same for cross platform.

I am lacking design skills and looking for a quick and ready solution. Is there any CSS or Javascript library to create the same user interface for all operating systems?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about which sections you feel look different? Perhaps a screenshot of what is different would help. The options page is just some HTML so if you apply CSS to it, it will work just like a standard web page. Not sure which UI feature you are talking about with "Popups" - do you mean popup windows, or what you get when you click on a Browser or Page Action?

Comment: I updated the question. I am lacking CSS and design skills. I want  ready CSS templates or library for doing this if possible.

Comment: Check outhttp://getbootstrap.com/ for a ready built CSS framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your update, perhaps you are looking for something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). There are many alternatives, for example see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214391/2022285

It should be noted that because the Chrome platform is designed to build on the web platform, it is conceivable to use any type of client JavaScript / CSS libraries in your Extensions (certain security policies notwithstanding)

Answer (score 2):

What you're requesting is a highly-demanded feature (though not implemented yet), see [Issue 25317: Help extensions authors make options pages with a consistent look](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25317) on Chromium's bug tracker.

When you implement an options page, you could take either of the two next methods:

1. Implement a pixel-perfect UI that looks identical on Linux, Mac and Windows.
2. Implement a UI using native controls of the relevant platforms.

I suggest to follow approach 2, because the most important part of an options page is the ability to quickly set preferences. This is achieved by using controls that are familiar to the user.

So, start with the basic unstyled HTML to get the main purpose right. E.g.:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="some-option-id">
    <span>Some option</span>
</label>
```

When you've done that, you could dress up the UI with CSS if you wish. But don't overdo it: users should still be able to recognize a checkbox.

If your app specifically demands for platform-specific colors, use CSS color keywords such as `ButtonFace`, `ButtonText`, `CaptionText`, etc. You can find more of these keywords [in Chromium's source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/web/WebColorName.cpp&q=buttonface&sq=package%3achromium&dr=C&l=43).

Comment: thanks I know the native is good but consistent look and feel will help porting the extension for other platforms and browsers, I suppose. That is why I asked for a CSS or Javascript library.

Comment: What problems are you trying to solve? If your HTML is sane, your options page will look all right on every platform/browser. Generic library recommendations are off-topic on Stack overflow, because answers tend to become outdated and opinionated. You should not use a library for the sake of using a library, but define the requirements, then look for a library. That makes it easier to find the right framework/library (Google is your friend).

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small UI kit especially for chrome extensions which resembles the exact look and feel of the default chrome settings page. Give it a look at http://code.compzets.com/css-kit-for-chrome-extensions/.

I have also used this for my own extension SimpleFill.

Comment: FYI, your work will be largely obsolete in Chrome 40+ because of `options_ui`, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2

Comment: @RobW Note that accepting Chrome-injected CSS is optional with OptionsV2, and the question is explicitly about overriding user-agent CSS.

Comment: @Xan The Q is about a consistent cross-platform UI. This answer promotes a library as "resembles exact look and feel of the default chrome settings page". I haven't looked at the linked framework, but the description sounds like something that is solved in Chrome 40+ with `options_ui` (aka OptionsV2). I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the info but Google also suggests to specify both `options_page` and `options_ui` so that Chrome 40+ can use `options_ui` whereas lower versions can use `options_page`. So i guess to have your options page look similar in all versions my `ui kit` could be quite useful.

Comment: @Ramswaroop Indeed, *for now*. But in February next year, most users will be using Chrome 40 and thus have `options_ui` by default. These styles only apply to options pages (at the moment), so if an extension has other extension pages (e.g. (browser action) popups, tabs), then your UI kit might be useful for these extensions even after Chrome 40.

Comment: Wow!!  Thanks!   I know there's options UI, but it's great to see your work.